# Run mutiple gerrit queries in python

Tags: python, git

I am trying to run a gerrit cherry pick query in python

```
query_to_run='git fetch https://gerritserver.com/projectname refs/changes/51/1151/1 ' + '&&' +  ' git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD'
```

I am getting error:
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref &&
Unexpected end of command stream

My code works with other gerrit queries but not this one, is it the && which is causing problem!

thanks
Pratibha

Comment: Please tell us what you're doing with `query_to_run`. It seems you're using the subprocess module. How?

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` token has no meaning to Git or Gerrit but is interpreted by your shell. By default the subprocess module doesn't pass off commands to the shell but runs the process directly, so the string in query_to_run is sent as a single command. To force subprocess.Popen(), subprocess.check_call() or whatever you're using to pass the command to a shell, pass shell=True:

```
subprocess.check_call(query_to_run, shell=True)
```

However, the use of shell=True is discouraged and is unnecessary in this case. What `&&` does is simply run one command and, if successful, run another command. It's basically equivalent to this sequence of Python statements:

```
subprocess.check_call(command1)
subprocess.check_call(command2)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer not have exceptions thrown when either of the commands fail:

```
subprocess.call(command1) != 0 and subprocess.call(command2) != 0
```

In addition to this, I strongly recommend making a good habit out of passing lists of arguments to process execution functions instead of strings. Passing strings works fine a lot of the time, but when arguments contain spaces you suddenly need to think about quoting.

Putting everything together, this is what *I* think your code should look like:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'fetch', 
                           'https://gerritserver.com/projectname',
                           'refs/changes/51/1151/1'])
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'cherry-pick', 'FETCH_HEAD'])
except (EnvironmentError, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    # Suitable error handling here. I'm not sure about
    # the possibility of EnvironmentError exceptions.
```

Also, a note on terminology: You're talking about Gerrit *queries*, but using that language might confuse people. By Gerrit query one usually means the Lucene query string entered into the search box in the UI (or the equivalent REST API).